# Removing extra characters from python string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Information I want to extract:**
The Locations Al Bayan and Nepal in a list `['Al Bayan' , 'Nepal']`

```
<div class="location">
<div class="listing-location">Location</div>
<div class="location-areas">
<span class="location">Al Bayan</span>
‪,‪
<span class="location">Nepal</span>
</div>
<div class="area-description"> 3.3 km from Mall of the Emirates </div>
</div>
```

**Code to extract the area:**

## Area

```
try:
    area= soup.find('div', 'location-areas')
    area_result= str(area.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8"))
    print([area_result])


except StandardError as e:
    area_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print area_result
```

**Output:**

```
"Al Bayanأ¢â‚¬آھ,أ¢â‚¬آھ
                        
                            Nepal"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
['Al Bayan', 'Nepal']
```

Comment: could your formulate the actual question in one sentence as a summary?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume `soup` is a `BeautifulSoup` instance, as such `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")` where `html_string` is your `html markup`.

Try this out:

`area_list = [area.get_text().strip().encode('utf-8') for area in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'location'})]
print area_list`